# How can I center a GridLayout in its relative layout parent?

Tags: android, css

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/behindChessBoard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/chessBoard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:columnCount="8"
        android:rowCount="8" >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell00"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="00" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell01"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="01" />

        ... so on and so forth...

    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

At the moment, the gridlayout is at the vvery top of the screen. I want to center it both horizontally and vertically. Any ideas?

EDIT: Note, the centerInParent="true" is not doing anything.

EDIT2: Found the answer, I had to set the gridlayout to wrap content and I had to also write android:layout_centerVertical="true"

Comment: put android:gravity="center" in parent relative layout.

Comment: If my answer meets your need then accept this answer. So that It helps later follower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you set the height and width as `match_parent` its not vertically centerd your content. Set the height and width as `wrap_content`.

Like this:

```
<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/chessBoard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_cotent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_cotent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:columnCount="8"
        android:rowCount="8" >
```